# using weka libraries in java for implementing neural network

Tags: java, neural-network, weka

I wanted to use weka libraries for neural network in my java code. On the weka website https://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+WEKA+in+your+Java+code, there are no examples for using neural network in java.

The basic classes of neural network in the weka libraries are found in **weka.classifiers.functions.neural** from http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/overview-summary.html.

I wanted to know if anyone has used the neural network implementation in their java code and if someone did, could he/she give me a simple explanation or example?

Note: I already know the basics of neural network.

Comment: You could try this -- https://github.com/amten/NeuralNetwork

Comment: @ode2k thanks. I'll try this..